# WSO2 EMM - Application blacklist not working

Tags: android, wso2-iot

I set policy to android devices on EMM, but as you can see in the picture it didn't show in device detail policy.

[image: device detail page]

here is the policy info:

```
Compliance Monitoring Type: warning

mobile application blacklist: 
com.instagram.android
jp.naver.line.android
```

as you can see in application list Line is already installed on device but notting show in policy and report.

[image: Device Compliance Monitoring Report]

How can I fix this issue?

More info:

wso2-emm version 1.1.0

server: win 7

device: galaxy note 10.1

Edit 1:

By replacing repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/emm in my pack with apps/emm folder downloaded from [github](http://github.com/wso2/product-emm). warning message shown on device but status in report tab under Device Compliance Monitoring report didn't updated. but when I click on device it show it.

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

also in device info page application list, device and location didn't show.

[image: image 3]

[here](http://ceit.aut.ac.ir/~9031020/complience-log.txt) is the wso2carbon log.

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I find the problem by checking differences in emm directory before and after changing it using `Araxis Merge`.

The problem was in line 231 emm\modules\notification.js, which is

```
var result = driver.query(sqlscripts.notifications.select21,
                    ctx.deviceid, ctx.operation);
```

as there is no sql query with the name `select21` under notifications query in sqlscripts\db.js and in previous version it was `select10`, so I change it and now things work fine :)